# Meaning of two double brackets ([][]) in Java

Tags: java, search, binary-search, square-bracket

What is the role of a pair of double brackets (`[][]`) in Java?

reference code(Leetcode 1351. Count Negative Numbers in a Sorted Matrix):

```java
class Solution {
  public int countNegatives(int[][] grid) {
    final int m = grid.length;
    final int n = grid[0].length;
    int ans = 0;
    int i = m - 1;
    int j = 0;

    while (i >= 0 && j < n) {
      if (grid[i][j] < 0) {
        ans += n - j;
        --i;
      } else {
        ++j;
      }
    }

    return ans;
  }
}
```

I tried finding about it on google but was not able to find anything regarding this. Please tell me why we use a double bracket here?

Comment: It is an array of which the elements are arrays of integers.

Comment: "I tried finding about it on google ..." - How about reading the Oracle Java tutorial?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: The clue is in the problem name:   .... Matrix ...

Comment: @Stephen_C For each question you may ask on SO, there's a book or a web site you could read instead. This could go with all the questions you asked on SO too. When you are a complete beginner in Java, SO is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is a two-dimensional array, or an array of arrays of `int`.

Comment: Technically, two-dimensional arrays don't exist in Java. Those imply a grid, where each nested array has the same length. In an `int[][]`, each nested array can have a different length. The term "array of arrays of `int`" is spot-on though.

Comment: @RobSpoor Which are colloquially called two-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, double brackets are used to represent 2D-Arrays (an array that contains arrays).

In your code example, this type is used to represent a 2D-Matrix containing integers. First coordinate correspond to rows and second to columns.

Example :

```
/*
    Consider 3x3 Matrix A
    | 1 2 3 |
    | 4 5 6 |
    | 7 8 9 |
*/

// Represent matrix as a 2D-Array
int[][] matrix = new int[][] {
    {1, 2, 3}, // 1st row
    {4, 5, 6}, // 2nd row
    {7, 8, 9}, // 3rd row
};

// Access coefficient at A(1, 2)
int value = matrix[0][1]; // A(1, 2) is at [0][1] in array because index start at 0.
```